# What does the '.' dot mean as a working directory?

Tags: shell, zsh, directory, pwd

**I'm not referring to the `.` you see in shell commands or in the output of `ls -a`.**

I just ran an install script for a vpn application, and after the command exited, my terminal prompt was *in* the `.` directory.

This is my `pwd` output:

```
➜ pwd
.
```

I've never seen anything like this. Anyone know what this is?

Comment: You have this ticket tagged with bash, shell, and zsh...can you clarify which shell you are using?

Comment: I'm on elementary OS and I'm not sure which shell the script used. My default shell is zsh but I still have bash installed

Comment: @dukeluke the first line of the script (shebang) will tell you

Comment: You can configure the prompt however you want. Something in your config tells the shell that the prompt should now contain a `.`. Run `echo $PS1` and mention the shell (bash, zsh, ...) you are using. That way we can find the reason

Comment: Also, take a look at the script, most likely it will change `$PS1` (the config of the first line of your prompt) there

Comment: @Garo, the screenshot looks like they executed `pwd`, and got the output `.`, so it would not just be the prompt that has it, but it would be the shell's idea of the working directory (assuming builtin `pwd`).

Comment: @dukeluke Can you tell us what the VPN application is? Is the installation script you run publicly available?

Comment: @dukeluke, check what e.g. `echo $ZSH_VERSION` and `echo $BASH_VERSION` say, they should help figure out which shell you have. Or if neither prints anything, then it's probably something else.

Comment: @Panki @likkachu the shebang is `#!/bin/sh`, but I think it's zsh, as that's my default shell and `echo $BASH_VERSION` outputs nothing whereas `echo #ZSH_VERSION` outputs 5.4.2

Comment: @fra-san the script was for Private Internet Access, and it's publicly available through their downloads page

Comment: @Garo I have a script in my .bashrc & .zshrc files that changes $PS1 to the current git branch, so `echo $PS1` just outputs that script

Answer (score 4):

That can happen when the current working directory has been deleted:

```
$ zsh -c 'mkdir dir; cd dir; rmdir $PWD; cd .; pwd; readlink /proc/self/cwd; command pwd'
.
/home/chazelas/dir (deleted)
pwd: couldn't find directory entry in ‘..’ with matching i-node
```

(the `cd .` causes zsh to double-check what its current directory is, and it reverts to `.` (the only possible valid path to the current working directory) when `getcwd()` returns with an error)